# How can I use javascript to attach url parameters to all outgoing requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Background

I have customers arriving on my landing page and I would like to attach url parameters such as `aff_id=X` to all outgoing traffic.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(i, node) {
  if (node.href != '#') {
    $(node).addClass('outgoing');
  }
});

$('.outgoing').attr('href', function(i, h) {
    if (h) {
        var arg_str = 's4=' + aff_id + '&s5=' + uuid;
        return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" + arg_str : "?" + arg_str);
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work on **all** outgoing requests such as form submit.

1. Is it possible to attach a listener via javascript to attach url parameters to all outgoing traffic?
2. Are there cleaner ways to attach url parameters to outgoing traffic on my landing page?

Comment: You could use a serviceWorker I think. Will try to write an example later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery:

```
var uuid = '',
    aff_id = '';
$('a, form').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var qstr = 's4=' + aff_id + '&s5=' + uuid;
    if ('a' === self.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase()) {
        var href = self.attr('href') || '';
        if (!href.match(/^#/)) {
            self.attr('href', href + (href.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '?' : '&') + qstr);
        }
    } else {
        var action = self.attr('action') || '';
        if (!action.match(/^#/)) {
            self.attr('action', action + (action.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '?' : '&') + qstr);
        }
    }
});
```

Could work as a simple quick-fix.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. However, this is specifically designed for forms and I am looking for something more general. There could be cases where `window.href` is modified directly by javascript and that will bypass this as well.